# In Angular, how to send URL as a parameter to the controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

From the view how to send a URL as a state parameter to the controller. When I'm sending a simple string everything works fine. However when I try to send a web url it doesn't work. I'm not receiving any error messages on the console as well.

Controller:

```
.controller('SubCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', 'DataProvider',
            function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, DataProvider){
              console.log($stateParams)
    $scope.whichCategory = $stateParams.category;
    alert($scope.whichCategory);
    DataProvider.getSubCategories($scope.whichCategory).then(function(categories){
        $scope.categories = categories.data;  
    });

  }]);
```

View:

```
 <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="category in categories" 
        href="#/categories/{{category.uri}}">
            <img src="{{category.img_url}}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{category.name}}">
 </ion-item>
```

Categories array object:

```
[{
name: "xxx",
uri: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/categories/xxx"
},
{
name: "yyy",
uri: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/categories/yyy"
}]
```

Comment: if you need that full url as a param would need to encode it. Not really clear what objective is

Comment: It looks that you've been using angular ui-router, right? What is console output from: $scope.whichCategory ?

Comment: @charlietfl  By encoding you mean ?

Comment: @Mike Yes I'm using angular ui-router

Comment: @charlietfl can u explain how i can do such encoding . From what I understand it seems like the problem has something to do with the forward slashes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to encode the URI, for example use the standard Javascript `encodeuricomponent` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).

In your controller add the following function:

```
$scope.encodeURL = function(uri) {
    return encodeURIComponent(uri);
};
```

And change this part in the view:

```
href="#/categories/{{category.uri}}"
```

To:

```
href="#/categories/{{ encodeURL(category.uri) }}"
```

Comment: Tried the above approach but still facing the issue. I'm not getting any parameters on the controller